# I don't understand where my React warning "can't call setstate on an unmounted component" comes from

Tags: reactjs, warnings, setstate

So I have the following code:

```
<UserConsumer>
{({ actions }) => {
    return (
        <span onClick={() => this.requestAuth(actions)}><MainButton name='Log in' /></span>
    )
}}
</UserConsumer>
```

Where this.requestAuth first sends a post request and - after succesful feedback - sets a state to 'true' using my actions event in my consumer. However, I have discovered - after experiencing - that I always get following error after wrapping my < span > in < UserConsumer >:

> Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
>       in Login (at App.js:207).

However, I don't understand why this happens.

This is my full Login.js code:

```
export default class Login extends Component  {

    constructor (props) {
        super (props)
        this.state = {
            pwVisible : false,
            pwUser: '',
            mailUser: '',
            feedback: null
        }
    }

    requestAuth = (actions) => {
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: process.env.REACT_APP_API_AUTH,
            data: {
                username: this.state.mailUser,
                password: this.state.pwUser
            }
        })
        .then(
            (response) => {
                console.log(response)
                this.setState({
                    feedback: "Alright, welcome back! I'm gonna log you in!"
                }, actions.logIn())
            }
        )
        .catch(
            (error) => {
                console.log(error)
                this.setState({
                    feedback: "Sorry, I think your e-mail or password is incorrect. Wanna try again?"
                })
            }
        );

    }
    render () {
        return (
            <div id='login'>
                <div id='loginBox'>
                    {Logo}
                    <form>
                        <input className='input100' value={this.state.mailUser} onChange={thisValue => this.setState({mailUser : thisValue.target.value}) } type='email' name='user' placeholder='firstname.lastname@ondernemersnetwerk.be' />
                        <input className='input100' value={this.state.pwUser} onChange={thisValue => this.setState({pwUser : thisValue.target.value}) } type={this.state.pwVisible? 'text' : 'password'} name='password' placeholder='Password' required />
                        <span className='pwIcon' onClick={this.state.pwVisible ? () => this.setState({pwVisible : false}) : () => this.setState({pwVisible : true})}>
                        {this.state.pwVisible ?
                            <Icon name='Visible' />
                        :
                            <Icon name='Hidden' />
                        }
                        </span>
                        <UserConsumer>
                            {({ actions }) => {
                                return (
                                    <span onClick={() => this.requestAuth(actions)}><MainButton name='Log in' /></span>
                                )
                            }}
                        </UserConsumer>
                    </form> 

                    <div className='gradientBorder'></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

Comment: Does this work fine without <Span/> ?

Comment: Can you provide a way to replicate the problem? Since it involves multiple components, the problem may specific to a component that wasn't shown. As for posted code, I don't see how `<UserConsumer>` is able to affect this.

Comment: Can you create a pen ?  https://codepen.io/

Comment: I've edited my post and posted the full Login.js code. This should be everything to understand why I'm having a warning.

Comment: The warning happens when I'm trying to set a state after Axios post method has been done in my .then() function

Comment: If you're positive it's caused by Login, you need to cancel Axios request on Login unmount. See https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation

Comment: The cancellation doesn't really help either. What I did to test the problem: I removed the UserConsumer tag around my span and removed the actions.logIn() in my requestAuth arrow function. Then, it seems I have no warning. So apparently the error happens when I'm calling my actions.logIn(). Which is set up in my App.js like this: `<UserProvider value={{actions: { logIn: event => { this.setState({ loggedIn: true }) }} }}><Route path='/' render={() => <Login />} /></UserProvider>`

Comment: Consider using `@`, otherwise users don't receive notifications. As I mentioned, several components are affected. And the problem likely happens in App. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem. The mistake I see in posted code is `setState(..., actions.logIn())`. It calls `actions.logIn` simultaneously with `setState`. That's a possible cause. In case you wanted to chain them, it should be `setState(..., actions.logIn)`. And if `logIn` results in Login unmount, `setState` is of no use at all since component instance will be discarded right away.

Comment: thank you @estus. I fixed the error by changing actions.logIn() -> to -> actions.logIn

Comment: Glad it was that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning because you call setState after component unmounted. Try setting a flag `_isMounted` and check before call `setState`:

```
export default class Login extends Component  {
    _isMounted = false;
    constructor (props) {
        super (props)
        this.state = {
            pwVisible : false,
            pwUser: '',
            mailUser: '',
            feedback: null
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this._isMounted = true;
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this._isMounted = false;
    }

    requestAuth = (actions) => {
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: process.env.REACT_APP_API_AUTH,
            data: {
                username: this.state.mailUser,
                password: this.state.pwUser
            }
        })
        .then(
            (response) => {
                console.log(response)
                if (this._isMounted) {
                    this.setState({
                        feedback: "Alright, welcome back! I'm gonna log you in!"
                    }, actions.logIn())
                }
            }
        )
        .catch(
            (error) => {
                console.log(error)
                if (this._isMounted) {
                    this.setState({
                        feedback: "Sorry, I think your e-mail or password is incorrect. Wanna try again?"
                    })
                }
            }
        );

    }
    render () {
        return (
            <div id='login'>
                <div id='loginBox'>
                    {Logo}
                    <form>
                        <input className='input100' value={this.state.mailUser} onChange={thisValue => this.setState({mailUser : thisValue.target.value}) } type='email' name='user' placeholder='firstname.lastname@ondernemersnetwerk.be' />
                        <input className='input100' value={this.state.pwUser} onChange={thisValue => this.setState({pwUser : thisValue.target.value}) } type={this.state.pwVisible? 'text' : 'password'} name='password' placeholder='Password' required />
                        <span className='pwIcon' onClick={this.state.pwVisible ? () => this.setState({pwVisible : false}) : () => this.setState({pwVisible : true})}>
                        {this.state.pwVisible ?
                            <Icon name='Visible' />
                        :
                            <Icon name='Hidden' />
                        }
                        </span>
                        <UserConsumer>
                            {({ actions }) => {
                                return (
                                    <span onClick={() => this.requestAuth(actions)}><MainButton name='Log in' /></span>
                                )
                            }}
                        </UserConsumer>
                    </form> 

                    <div className='gradientBorder'></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I there, sorry for the late response. I did the same as you and using console.log I noticed that the this._isMounted returns true even in my Axios. So apparently, the component is still mounted? I don't understand why I'm having the error then.

Comment: I fixed the error by changing actions.logIn() -> to -> actions.logIn